# Change default java module structure in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I would like to know how to change the default java module structure in IntelliJ IDEA from:

```
module_name/src
```

Where src is marked as 'sources', to:

```
module_name/src
              /main/java
              /test/java
```

Where main/java is marked as sources and test/java marked as test sources.

Is there a way that I can make this the default so I don't have to manually do it each time?

Comment: this is a maven related question? would help to add that in title and/or body. i see you have added to tags but its more useful to add to body too.

Comment: It's not relating to the maven tool, but the layout I would like as my default is a maven one (more commonly standard now)

Comment: Why has my post been changed to say "in maven"? It's not in maven it's in Idea.  The question now doesn't make sense?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @tgkprog - I don't follow?

Comment: Your question is perfectly valid, I now use the Maven style layout even if the project is not build by Maven. But it seems that IntelliJ does not allow to customize default src/test root directories.

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumeDarmont, it seems my question has be derailed by edits and I've now ended up with responses to a question that wasn't mine.  Thanks again.

Comment: imrichardcole you can edit your question yourself. in its original form it was not clear that it was about intellij-idea. anyway you now have an answer for intellij-idea, do try it out and comment on the answer if it did not work or choose it as the right one. thank you [FAQ] <-- read this, will help using the site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a project set up to your specifications and then save it as a template that will be available when you create a new project.

See the IntelliJ documentation for [Saving Project as Template]
(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/save-project-as-template-dialog.html).

Answer (score 2):

The right way - create a pom.xml and reorganise the source so that it will work with maven. After it - just import pom.xml into Idea, it will recognise maven project structure automatically.

The manual way - use "Module settings" -> "Sources" and manually change the source folders for your structure. See the screen example here http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/File:Project_structure_dialog_left_hand_pane.png

Comment: Sorry but my question was changed by some moderators and now it doesn't make sense.